# Python create variable for each item

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

I have a list of items. like `banana`, `apple`, `orange` etc. Each of these has it´s properties, like `banana`: `'name': 'banana','color': 'yellow'` etc.

What I'm trying to do is create variable's for each item. So i can call it like
`fruit.banana['color']` and get the value `yellow` back.

Code example:

```
fruits =  cur.fetchall()
for fruittarget in fruits:
    fruit = fruittarget['name']
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits where name = %s ;",(fruit))
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    name = rows["name"]
    fruitfunc = {name: rows['name']}
    fruitfunc[rows['name']] = {'color': rows['color']}
print fruitfunc[banana]['color']
```

Problem is that only works for the very last one in the for each. 
how do i make a `fruitfunc.banana['color']`, `fruitfunc.potato['color']`?
I want to set the variable name with a variable like `getfruit + name = fruitfunc`. So for each item in the list a varible is created.

Comment: Your indention is broken.

Comment: Don't do this. Create a dictionary called `fruits` and make each `fruit` a key in that. Dynamically creating top level variables makes your code harder to read and more error prone.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: The OP is doing just that; the wording is just rather poorly choosen.

Comment: You appear to confuse local variable names (which you should not generate, just don't) with dictionary keys (great idea, do generate those!). But you are also not explaining your expected output very well.

Comment: And in case I misread you and you *are* trying to generate local names, the obligatory link to read is http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: It´s hard to explain but in, each item will have about 100 properties, and if i would combine it to one dict, it would be hughe, and i would not be sure how to get the property of one item. What i want to get is simply the value of the item, like orange['color'] or banana['drinks'] etc. I assume i could do this with dict only, i just dont know how to make sub dict´s in a dict sort of say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits = {'banana': {'color': 'yellow'}, 'potato': {'color': 'beige'}}
```

Use the names as the keys. To get the colour of the banana, refer to `fruits['banana']['color']`.

Comment: I'm going to do my best not to make jokes about massive dicts, haha. Anyway, dicts seem to be (from what I've read and experienced) fast, though they are quite memory-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
# this class simulates cur.fetchall and cur.execute
# to stick with your example code

class Database:
    data = [{"name":"banana","color":"yellow"},{"name":"red_apple","color":"red"}]
    def execute(self,ignored,name):
        for element in self.data :
            if element["name"] == name:
                return element
    def fetchall(self):
        return self.data

cur    = Database()
fruits = cur.fetchall()
mydict = {}
for fruit in fruits :
    fruit_name            = fruit["name"]
    fruit_dict            = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits where name = %s ;",fruit_name)
    mydict[fruit["name"]] = fruit_dict

print "---"
print mydict    
print mydict["red_apple"]
print mydict["banana"]["color"]
```

trace :

```
>>> ---
{'red_apple': {'color': 'red', 'name': 'red_apple'}, 'banana': {'color': 'yellow', 'name': 'banana'}}
{'color': 'red', 'name': 'red_apple'}
yellow
>>>
```

Suggested reading (and libraries that do just that) :

- [db_row](http://opensource.theopalgroup.com/files/db_row.html)
- [dtuple](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81252/)
- [sqlobject](http://sqlobject.org/)
- [sqlsoup](https://sqlsoup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)
- [The big list of other relational mappers and sql wrappers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HigherLevelDatabaseProgramming)